PowerShell for PowerBI: Can we export a list of Reports that show both corresponding WorkspaceID and DatasetID?
I need to carry out an Admin-related task, I need to be able to document every report and dataset in every workspace. I've achieved partial success and would kindly ask for your assistance.
We can get the list of workspaces
workspaces
Get-PowerBIWorkspace -Scope Organization -All | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File c:\PowerBIWorkspaces.json

we can get the list of reports and datasets separately
reports

$timesamp = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HHmmss")
$namefolder = "C:\filepath\Admin\"
$namefile = "workspace_reports_meta" + "_" + $timesamp
$extension = ".json" 
$filenamestring = $namefolder + $namefile + $extension
$Result = $filenamestring
Get-PowerBIReport -Scope Organization | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File $Result



datasets

$timesamp = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HHmmss")
$namefolder = "C:\filepath\Admin\"
$namefile = "workspace_datasets_meta" + "_" + $timesamp
$extension = ".json" 
$filenamestring = $namefolder + $namefile + $extension
$Result = $filenamestring
Get-PowerBIDataset -Scope Organization | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File $Result


But sadly, I've not found the solution to either combine these together in any form, particularly as I can't export a list of reports that contains corresponding workspaceIDs :(
Thank you community
